# htaccess rewrite doesn't work when path has same name as file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a strange problem. Here are two examples of a URL rewrite in my htaccess file. The first one doesn't work and returns the variable for "query" as null in the PHP file.

```
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)$ search.php?query=$1
```

The second one (that I have used as a test) works perfectly fine.

```
RewriteRule ^foo/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)$ search.php?query=$1
```

I have found that the problem is that the beginning of the pattern cannot be the same as the name of the php file I'm using with it. This has always worked for me, and I am only now encountering this problem as I have moved to a new server.

Is there some kind of setting that is causing this?

Comment: Is it wordpress? Cuz, wp doesnt like you using certain words, search being one of them.  If youre using /search/somekeyword, wp might already be using /search/

Comment: @DougCassidy No, it's not wordpress or any other CMS/framework.

Comment: it seems the Multiviews issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place this line on top of your .htaccess to turn off `MultiViews` option:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: Thanks! Completely forgot about MultiViews. Must be set as default on this server.